# Why MKMetersBetweenMapPoints and distanceFromLocation return different values?

Tags: mapkit, core-location, distance

I'm trying to remove a dependency from `MKMapKit` for one of our framework. We use `MKMapKit` only to calculate the distance between two coordinates, using the  function `MKMetersBetweenMapPoints`.

Implementing the same code but using `CLLocation` object and the `distanceFromLocation` method I receive different results. The error is less than one meter.

This is the test I'm running

```
- (double)distanceWithMapKitFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromLocationCoordinate2D toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)toLocationCoordinate2D
{
    MKMapPoint mapPointFrom = MKMapPointForCoordinate(fromLocationCoordinate2D);
    MKMapPoint mapPointTo = MKMapPointForCoordinate(toLocationCoordinate2D);
    return MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(mapPointFrom, mapPointTo) / 1000;
}

- (double)distanceWithCoreLocationFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)fromLocationCoordinate2D toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)toLocationCoordinate2D
{

    CLLocation *fromLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:fromLocationCoordinate2D.latitude longitude:fromLocationCoordinate2D.longitude];
    CLLocation *toLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:toLocationCoordinate2D.latitude longitude:toLocationCoordinate2D.longitude];

    return [fromLocation distanceFromLocation:toLocation] / 1000;
}

- (void)testDistanceWithoutMapKit
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord1 = RandomCoordinate2D();
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord2 = RandomCoordinate2D();

        double distance1 = [self distanceWithMapKitFrom:coord1 toCoordinate:coord2];
        double distance2 = [self distanceWithCoreLocationFrom:coord1 toCoordinate:coord2];

        NSLog(@"%f %f %f", distance1, distance2, distance2 - distance1);

        XCTAssertEqual(distance1, distance2);
    }
}
```

The `RandomCoordinate2D` function can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/justin/5545529)

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?